# Plotly : How can I add a Scatterpolar over a Barpolar plot?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am trying to plot Scatterpolar plots over a Barpolar plot (Barpolar is used to build the layout of the Scatterpolar plot).

I am using the following code to plot the figure :

```
########################################################################
# Make background layout
########################################################################
# https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Barpolar.html
layout_radius = 2.8
num_slices = 5
theta = [(i + 1.5) * 360 / num_slices for i in range(num_slices)]
width = [360 / num_slices for _ in range(num_slices)]
vals = [layout_radius for _ in range(num_slices)]
# blue = rgba(50, 144, 196, 0.2) = Governance
# orange = rgba(183, 87, 39, 0.2) = Design
# yellow = rgba(217, 166, 25, 0.2) = Implementation
# green = rgba(55, 121, 62, 0.2) = Verification
# brown = rgba(121, 31, 23, 0.2) = Operations
colors = ['rgba(50, 144, 196, 0.2)', 'rgba(183, 87, 39, 0.2)', 'rgba(217, 166, 25, 0.2)',
          'rgba(55, 121, 62, 0.2)', 'rgba(121, 31, 23, 0.2)']
labels = ["Governance",  "Design", "Implementation",
          "Verification", "Operations"]
barpolar_plots = [go.Barpolar(r=[r], theta=[t], width=[w], name=n, marker_color=[c])
                  for r, t, w, n, c in zip(vals, theta, width, labels, colors)]
layout = go.Figure()

# Align backgorund
angular_tickvals = [(i + 1) * 360 / num_slices for i in range(num_slices)]
layout.update_layout(polar_angularaxis_tickvals=angular_tickvals)
# Remove legends
layout_options = {}
layout_options["showlegend"] = True
layout_options["polar_angularaxis_showticklabels"] = False
layout.update_layout(**layout_options)
########################################################################
########################################################################
# Add plots on Layout
########################################################################
layout.add_traces(barpolar_plots)

layout.add_traces([go.Scatterpolar(r=current_maturity_score_dataframe,
                                   theta=maturity_score_labels_dataframe),
                   go.Scatterpolar(r=latest_maturity_score_dataframe,
                                   theta=maturity_score_labels_dataframe)])
```

On the rendered image I see that Plotly adds both plots to the legend but the Scatterpolar does not appear : [image]

I am also able to plot the Scatterpolars without the Barpolars :
[image]
How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

- your sample code does not include building a **scatter polar**.  Hence I have used the reference example https://plotly.com/python/polar-chart/#polar-chart-with-plotly-express
- to create a **scatter polar** trace on top of a **bar polar**

  1. give the **scatter polar** it's own axis `fig.update_traces(subplot="polar2")`
  2. ensure that **domain** is same for both polar axes `update_layout({ax:{"domain":{"x":[0,1]}} for ax in ["polar","polar2"]})`
  3. make background of **scatter polar** transparent. `update_layout(polar2={"bgcolor":"rgba(0,0,0,0)"})`

Full code below

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

########################################################################
# Make background layout
########################################################################
# https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.graph_objects.Barpolar.html
layout_radius = 2.8
num_slices = 5
theta = [(i + 1.5) * 360 / num_slices for i in range(num_slices)]
width = [360 / num_slices for _ in range(num_slices)]
vals = [layout_radius for _ in range(num_slices)]
# blue = rgba(50, 144, 196, 0.2) = Governance
# orange = rgba(183, 87, 39, 0.2) = Design
# yellow = rgba(217, 166, 25, 0.2) = Implementation
# green = rgba(55, 121, 62, 0.2) = Verification
# brown = rgba(121, 31, 23, 0.2) = Operations
colors = ['rgba(50, 144, 196, 0.2)', 'rgba(183, 87, 39, 0.2)', 'rgba(217, 166, 25, 0.2)',
          'rgba(55, 121, 62, 0.2)', 'rgba(121, 31, 23, 0.2)']
labels = ["Governance",  "Design", "Implementation",
          "Verification", "Operations"]
barpolar_plots = [go.Barpolar(r=[r], theta=[t], width=[w], name=n, marker_color=[c])
                  for r, t, w, n, c in zip(vals, theta, width, labels, colors)]
layout = go.Figure()

# Align backgorund
angular_tickvals = [(i + 1) * 360 / num_slices for i in range(num_slices)]
layout.update_layout(polar_angularaxis_tickvals=angular_tickvals)
# Remove legends
layout_options = {}
layout_options["showlegend"] = True
layout_options["polar_angularaxis_showticklabels"] = False
layout.update_layout(**layout_options)
########################################################################
########################################################################
# Add plots on Layout
########################################################################
layout.add_traces(barpolar_plots)

df = px.data.wind()
fig = px.scatter_polar(df, r="frequency", theta="direction")
fig.update_traces(subplot="polar2")

layout = layout.add_traces(fig.data).update_layout({ax:{"domain":{"x":[0,1]}} for ax in ["polar","polar2"]})
layout.update_layout(polar2={"bgcolor":"rgba(0,0,0,0)"})
```

[image]